# Can I implement multiple files selections  for File Upload in RichFace, or implement a custom tag for this using javascript?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, richfaces

I want to implement multiple files selection for File Upload in RichFace, and I found [a demo here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf;jsessionid=BCE786DE9AEFB9699010A8F8AE9C628C?c=fileUpload&tab=usage).

But if I can implement multiple files selection like we can do that on Windows normally, it will be a good experience for users.

If this is not support in RichFace, how can I implment a custom tag for this using javascript?

Could you comment out your idea and suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean selecting multiple files in the "file chooser" dialog that the browser pops up ... or loading multiple files into the "Uploaded Files Info" portion of the demo application you've linked to?

Comment: Yes, exactly, sorry for I missed your comment.

Comment: See the discussion where this is being implemented here:https://community.jboss.org/thread/228333

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this issue was fixed in RichFaces v4.5.0.Alpha1: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12224 
But currently available version of RichFaces is 4.3.4.Final, so this feature is not yet available.