# Centering a Floating div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, addthis

I am stuck. Here is what I have going on, I have an AddThis sharing widget next to a main image on a webpage. The image changes sizes and I need the AddThis to change its placement with the image dynamically. I asked this in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691304/fluid-spacing-for-a-div) and through another forum I was able to get some help. Now AddThis and the image align properly and everything seems to be going in the right direction, however the image is no longer centered. I need this image to be centered on the page but I cannot figure out how to do this because I had to float the div containing the image and AddThis. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="feature-container">
<div style="min-height:100px; min-width:100px; position:relative; float:left; ">
<div style="text-align:center;"><img class="feature-image" 
     src="/Images/test.jpg" width="300px;" alt="test" /></div>
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:-40px;">
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_16x16_style">
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300
                 /addthis_widget.js"></script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to center this? I can use a straight CSS solution or a solution using jQuery and CSS. Please provide examples.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE of the page](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/WY9YX/18/).

[Here is a page](http://www.ubhape2.com/test-placement.html) that has the most up to date code I am attempting.

Comment: _"I had to float the div"_ - Why? I don't know that I can suggest anything without seeing some of the surrounding elements.

Comment: @nnnnnn - It is the way the AddThis was acting. To get it to position relative to the image it had to be floated.

Comment: can you provide a sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Raminson - Added fiddle in the question.

Comment: @Lynda apart from everything that's going on here, I haven't seen you clear your floats once. While this is surely not the issue that you're having, it will cause other issues down the road. [This is an article I'd found helpful when trying to explain clearing floats to someone else.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) -- *EDIT* Also, is there anyway we can see a live working example?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - Below the above code there is a `<br class="clear" />` aka `style="clear:both;" what is floating and prevents further issues. Thanks for pointing that out. And I created a fiddle. See the link at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var pos = $('.center').width() - $('img').width();
$('.center').css('margin-left', pos);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WY9YX/4/

Comment: My comment that I made earlier seems to have disappeared. I apologize if this shows up twice. I implemented your js and it works but creates a couple other errors. The content below the image is thrown off and the page is very wide now vs sticking to the 940px width. I edited the fiddle to include this extra content and I added a link to the page with the most recent code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Lynda you are welcome. try this: `$('.center').css('margin-left', pos/2)`; if the width of your container is 940px and width of the image is 300px you can center the element by calculating (940 - width of image (300)) => 640px / 2 => 320px, so `margin-left:320px`, i can see your uppermost wrapper is not centered if you want to center the elements properly you should center the wrapper too:  `margin: 0 auto`;

Comment: It works with one slight glitch! The code in your comment worked after I fiddled with what it was pulling its information from. Instead of using `.center` I created another div to wrap just the image and the AddThis code. Then instead of using `$('img').width();` I added a class to the main image and used that. Now the only problem I can see is The main image and the logo below it are slightly off center. It may be off center by 20px but it is noticeable. Any ideas how to correct for that? Note: The Fiddle has been updated.

Comment: One more thing that seems to be a bit strange. If I hit CTRL + SHIFT + R in Firefox (to override and reload the cache) the image kicks over to the right a bit. I assume this is a glitch in FF and not the code. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure the content of your *'im-center'*, since I add an inline style（text-align:center;） as below, tested it and works fine on ie 8.

```
<div class="img-center" style="text-align:center;">
  <img src="test.jpg" alt="test" />
</div>
```

Define a fixed width for center div would be OK, if this not requries a fixed width, @Raminson's jquery solution is better. I really want to know if we can implement this with pure css

```
<div id="top" class="wrap_fullwidth">
    <div class="center" style="width:400px;">
<div style="min-height:100px; min-width:100px; position:relative; float:left; ">
    <div style="text-align:center;"><img src="http://www.ubhape2.com/Images/test.jpg" alt="test" /></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:-40px;">
        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_16x16_style">
            <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>​​​
```

Comment: That is what the class `img-center` is. I edited post to reflect that. Also that does not work.

Comment: What is your web browser? I tested it on IE8.

Comment: It is strange, I also tried this on chrome, it is OK. The root cause is the 'float:left' of parent container? You can remove the 'float:left' tempororily first, and debug it step by step.

Comment: I added a fiddle in my question. To remove the float messes up the alignment of the AddThis widget.

Comment: ... By my test on the fiddle, the float div will not be centred in the parent div (center div). otherwise define a fixed width for the parent div, please see the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/WY9YX/14/

Comment: I have read of ways to center a floated div using pure css however to keep AddThis next to the image and keep its spacing regardless of the image size is what is throwing everything else off. I think JS will be needed here unless some trickery can be done in CSS that I am not aware of nor have others posted elsewhere.

Comment: Got it, js is economic and good solution for your situation, learnt  more from your question,thank you. BTW, do you and @Raminson have intersting in my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730040/can-i-implement-multiple-files-selections-for-file-upload-in-richface-or-imple

Comment: Glad you were able to learn something. And I am sorry I cannot help you with your question. I do not know the answer.

Answer (score -4):

Try to apply `margin: 0 auto;` CSS rule to the div.